# Ranging multiple beacons in background and determine dwell time for each of the beacon in background

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon, altbeacon, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using altbeacon library in my BLE Project. I want to enable background scanning for beacons. Since I am not expecting users to have Bluetooth turned on all the time, I am using GPS location of the user to determine whether I need to turn Bluetooth on to scan for beacons in background. I am using Bootstrap notifier to trigger `didEnterRegion` and then using `RangeNotifier` to determine the Major, Minor and distance values of the device. I want to trigger an event if the user dwells at a distance of 2-5 mts for 30s. How can I do this from background? Currently using the default setting of 10s scanning and 5 mins of snooze helps me monitor the region defined by my UUID but when ranging for the major, minor and distance the scan lasts only for 1 second which also does not help me see all the beacons around as I am using ~2hz frequency. Next scan takes place only after 5 mins. I am skeptical to reduce the 5 mins time to 10s as I do not want user to feel the app is consuming battery if he leaves the Bluetooth on for too long.

So finally my questions are:

1. How can I increase the scan period or frequency of scanning when ranging in background so that I can see all the beacons around in the region?
2. Can I get the UUID, major, minor and dwell time of the beacon when it exits the region and `didExitRegion` is called?

Comment: Hey @Nikhil Kashid hav u saolved this issue?? plz help me how to find shortest distance between multiple beacons.

Comment: Hi Aruna, You can do that using the RSSI value of the beacon observed over some period of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would add custom logic to control background mode.  Stay in foreground mode for 30 seconds or so after entering the geofence, then go to background mode.
2. If your monitored region has major and minor defined, you can read these fields out of id 2 and id3 on region exit.   There is no automatic tracking of dwell time, but you can set a timestamp in your app on region entry, and subtract it from another timestamp your app records on region exit.

Comment: 1. Do you recommend using a foreground service for this? I do not want to launch the activity when user just sees the beacon. Instead I would want to give him a notification when we are sure about the user being in "immediate" zone from the beacon. 

2. I am monitoring region only with UUID defined since there maybe cases where there are several major and minor with same UUID. So in this case I am not able to see which beacon has the user exited among a group of beacons that the app was seeing.

Comment: (1) I would simply call BeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true) when you enter the geofence, and start a 30 second timer to set it back to false when the timer goes off.  (2) It is hard to know which beacon caused an exit event when you have regions based on UUID.  The best you can do is track a list of all beacons seen since the last region entry event, along with the last detection timestamp.  (you can keep this list up to date in the ranging callback) then when the region exit event fires, you can look for the beacon most recently seen and assume that one is the one that last disappeared.

Comment: This helps. Thank you